# Where can I ask a question about formal logic?

Tags: discussion

Three weeks ago I asked a question and got no answer. The question involves an extension to traditional formal logic. I have a short paper that shows that the extension obeys formal rules and is connected to networks, sets, files and other things. Someone must have thought of this before, so I want to find where to look it up. What is the proper web site for this kind of question?

Comment: Looking at your original question, I would have thought that https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a good bet - however please do read their help section to check you are asking as they expect and it is on topic. Do note you got an upvote on this site for your question, which means one person at least felt the question was on-topic and worthwhile on the site. That's not the same as guaranteeing an answer. Mathematics Stack Exchange is far more popular, so more likely you will find an expert willing and able to engage on a specific topic

Comment: Also relevant: "Where can I ask a question about where can I ask a question about?"  The answer to this is usually the meta site.  If you click the community button in the top right you should see a meta AI stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I ask a question about formal logic?

- https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lo.logic
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic